# Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z + n} + \frac{1}{z-n}$ is absolutely convergent for all $z \in \mathbb{H}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

I need to show that the series
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z + n} + \frac{1}{z-n}
$$
is absolutely convergent for all $z$ in the complex upper half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Im(z) > 0 \}$.
Taking modulus of each term, I get
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{z + n} + \frac{1}{z-n} \right| = 2|z| \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{| z^2 - n^2 |}.
$$
I think I want to be able to compare this to the series
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
which converges, and so conclude that the original series is absolutely convergent, but I don't know how to do that. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Try to estimate $|n^2-z^2|\ge n^2-|z|^2$, so for $n>|z|$ your series terms are majorated by $\frac{1}{n^2-|z|^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. We assume $\Im(z) > 0$. One may write, as $n \to \infty$
$$
\left| \frac{1}{z + n} + \frac{1}{z-n} \right| = \frac1{n^2}\cdot \frac{2|z|}{|\frac{z^2}{n^2}-1 |}\le \frac1{n^2}\cdot \frac{2|z|}{\left|\frac{|z|^2}{n^2}-1\right|} \sim \frac{2|z|}{n^2}
$$ giving the absolute convergence for the initial series.

Comment: Why do you need $\Im(z) > 0$?

Comment: @A.G. If $\Im(z) = 0$ then there is a possibility that the sum is not well-defined, as the denominator can become zero for some $n$. Otherwise, I don't think it plays any role.

Comment: @Brahadeesh It does not matter that the denominator is not defined for finitely many $n$. What matters is that it is defined for all $n$ large enough. It is *pointwise* absolute convergence question.

Comment: I just gave the same frame: the OP question is to prove it for $z \in \mathbb{H}$.